# is sqlite.net-pcl free for sqlchiper

Tags: xamarin, sqlcipher, sqlite.net

Can I use sqlite-net with sqlcipher on Xamarin for free?

From the [website](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlcipher-for-xamarin-ios), the price stated 499, but from the [repo](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL), it looks like it is an open source project - MIT.

Comment: SQLCipher is also available via the open-source community edition @ zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite.NET is an open source project **(Free)**:

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net (Main)

https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL (Fork)

SQLCipher is a third party **paid** library by Zetetic LLC(https://www.zetetic.net/)

There is also an open source version(https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/)

Comment: SQLCipher is also available via the open-source community edition @ https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/open-source/